# Trouble passing a JsonSerializerSetting from one assembly via an Action parameter to another assembly

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-assembly

Using Json.Net, I am trying to pass a JsonSerializerSettings object as one of the parameters of an Action.

The SerializerSettings is in assembly A:

```
public static class SerializerSettings
{
    public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Jss = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
           { new StringEnumConverter(), new NullStringConverter() }
    };
}
```

(the NullStringConverter is just a custom converter inheriting from JsonConverter)

for brevity:

```
public class NullStringConverter : JsonConverter
{}
```

I may not be using the best or proper terminology to describe this but, then from assembly B the method defined below is passed as a pointer to assembly A and there in assembly A it is invoked with its parameters that include the JsonSerializerSettings defined above.

```
private static void Investigated<TRequest, TResponse>(string data, JsonSerializerSettings jss) where TRequest : IBaseRequest where TResponse : IBaseResponse
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) || jss == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Bad Data");
    else
    {
        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(data, jss);
    }
}
```

In debugger i see the data string is good, jss is properly set, but the deserialization completes with all values in the 'response' object being null or default values.

If instead i move the same JsonSerializerSettings local to assembly B, deserialization comes out fine...

I even tried to create a new JsonSerializerSettings FROM the one passed in, but that had the same null/default results.

My first inclination is to suspect it is not possible pass/use a JsonSerializerSettings from one assembly to/in another in this way, a static object as a action's parameter?

Might i be doing anything obviously wrong.

I apologia in advance to anyone feeling my question is not well formed, lacks information, or otherwise answered elsewhere, im trying to follow the rules...

Comment: Usually when you get a null response, it's because the object you tried to map your data to is not matching up. Did you verify that `TResponse` is in fact properly mapped to your data?

Comment: yes sir, from locally defining the JsonSerializer and getting proper results confirmed I had a properly mapped TResponse object.

Comment: I've added a more complete answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. JsonConvert returns nulls or defaults

The kind symptoms that you described that results your `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method returning an object with nulls or defaults, occurs when you do not map your objects properly. Here is a small example to illustrate it.

```
class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public string BarName { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "One"
    };  
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
    
    
    var bar = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bar>(json);
}
```

Here is the result of `bar`:

```
bar = { BarId = 0, BarName = null }
```

> Incorrect mapping will result in **nulls and defaults**.

---

## 2. Pay attention to details when using a custom JsonConverter

Going further with the example above, when using a `JsonConverter` you also have to be aware of the mapping as well, as it's more prone to produce the same kind of problems from small typos or other errors.

**MyCustomJsonSerializerSettings**

```
public static class MyCustomJsonSerializerSettings
{
    private static JsonSerializerSettings _jss;
    
    public static JsonSerializerSettings Jss
    {
        get { return _jss; }
        private set { _jss = value; }
    }
    
    static MyCustomJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        _jss = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
            {
                new FooToBarConverter()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**FooToBarConverter**

```
public class FooToBarConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, 
        object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Foo foo = (Foo)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("BarId", new JValue(foo.Id));     // make sure of your mapping!
        jo.Add("BarName", new JValue(foo.Name)); // make sure of your mapping!
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> Make sure that you are properly mapping the object in the custom converter.

#### Putting it all together...

```
void Main()
{
    var foo = new Foo()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "One"
    };  
    
    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo);
    var bar = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bar>(json); // nulls/defaults
    
    JsonSerializerSettings jss = MyCustomJsonSerializerSettings.Jss;
    string json2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, jss); // note jss
    var bar2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bar>(json2); // as expected!
}
```

---

## 3. Portability of the Converter Between Assemblies

> To be 100% certain that the converters will get passed along with your settings, you can always do something like this

```
public class MyCustomJsonSerializerSettings // not a static class
{
    private static JsonSerializerSettings _jss;
    
    public static JsonSerializerSettings Jss
    {
        get { return _jss; }
        private set { _jss = value; }
    }
    
    static MyCustomJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        _jss = new JsonSerializerSettings { ... };
    }

    private class FooToBarConverter : JsonConverter // note that it is contained within
                                                    // the class
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what your suggesting, I'll take another look but with correct results when defining the JsonSerializer Settings in the assembly that the deserialization is happening proved to me the object was mapped ok

Comment: @axa No problem. If you're having a more specific question with your converter, you can ask a new question. Just don't forget to provide the link

Comment: ok, I'm going to go back and look at changing the serializerSettings feild to property as suggested, I know json can be particular with these

Comment: @axa - also take a look at the last addition, to make sure that the converters are contained with the settings. There might be something going on in the manner you are passing it around assemblies.

Comment: yes I'm going to take a gander at each of these items.  thanks for taking the time really.

Comment: Turns out I seem to misunderstand what the MissingMemberHandling set as error will do...  when wrapped in a try catch, i thought it would raise an exception, but seemingly it just returned a null object without raising an exception.  Im likely doing something wrong here, but marking this answer accepted as it at least helped me take a deeper look into the serializer settings.